# WHMCS 5.1 upgrade to version 7.1

Tags: whmcs

WHMCS 5.1 upgrade to version 7.1 
or a migration wizard from the version of WHMCS 5.1 to that of version 7.1

because it's no longer supported

Answer (score 1):

There is no migration tool/wizard or automatic way to update from version 5.1. More importantly, WHMCS version 7.1 has reached EOL. You won't be able to download it anymore.

You should upgrade to 7.6. And your best bet is to do a manual update [suggested here](https://docs.whmcs.com/Updating#Update_Steps).

Here are the details of [WHMCS Version & LTS Schedule](https://docs.whmcs.com/Long_Term_Support#WHMCS_Version_.26_LTS_Schedule)